# T-SQL tool that requires a semicolon to end statements

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have what is probably a rather unusual question. Is there **a T-SQL tool** that *requires* using a semicolon to terminate statements? I know that it's not required to use semicolons with **SQL Server 2008 R1**, which is what I'm connecting to, but I actually would like to be forced to use it for running update queries. I'm sure we're all aware of the dangers of writing a query like the one below in the middle of a sql pad, and then highlighting it and running it (which is unfortunately something I tend to do a lot):

```
UPDATE dbo.Customers
SET ZipCode = '40223'
WHERE Name = 'Bob Loblaw'
```

... because you only have to miss-select your text once to nuke all your customer's zipcodes!

So, ideally, I'd like to continue doing most of my sql work in **SQL Server Management Studio**, but have a separate pad open (in a tool that requires semicolons) and only allow myself to write data manipulation queries over there. This would give me **great** peace of mind, because I'd know I could never miss-select my commonly used update queries. If I did, it wouldn't run, because it wouldn't have a semicolon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than relying on semicolons (a misplaced semicolon could also cause the problem you are describing), better to rely on transactions.

Set up your query tool to require a commit, and you will have the option rollback if necessary.

In SSMS, you can do this by checking the option `SET IMPLICIT TRANSACTIONS` under Tools/Options/Query Execution/SQL Server/ANSI. Or, you can turn it on with this command:

```
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON
```

**[SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187807.aspx)**

> When ON, SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS sets the connection into implicit
>   transaction mode. When OFF, it returns the connection to autocommit
>   transaction mode.
>
> When a connection is in implicit transaction mode and the connection
>   is not currently in a transaction, executing any of the following
>   statements starts a transaction:
>
> ALTER TABLE FETCH REVOKE BEGIN TRANSACTION GRANT SELECT CREATE INSERT
>   TRUNCATE TABLE DELETE OPEN UPDATE DROP
>
> If the connection is already in
>   an open transaction, the statements do not start a new transaction.
>
> Transactions that are automatically opened as the result of this
>   setting being ON **must be explicitly committed or rolled back** by the
>   user at the end of the transaction. Otherwise, the transaction and all
>   of the data changes it contains are rolled back when the user
>   disconnects. After a transaction is committed, executing one of the
>   statements above starts a new transaction.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea. Any idea if it's possible to setup SSMS to require transactions? I don't see that in the options.

Comment: Check under Tools, Options, Query Execution, SQL Server, ANSI, SET IMPLICIT TRANSACTIONS.

Comment: Beat me to it! I'll give it a try and post back. Thanks!

Comment: Started using this technique and I LOVE it! It's exactly what I was looking for -- takes almost all the anxiety away from running queries in a production environment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Some T-SQL statement require the previous statements to be terminated (MERGE, WITH for a CTE) but there is no blanket requirement.

It will be added later as far as I know and it is recommended.

To avoid fubaring your data (which you can only do win production with permissions)

- use different credentials for read and writes/deploys
- use stored procedures where possible
- prepare your scripts on non-production servers and deploy as whole scripts
- take database snapshots/backups before running scripts
- have a BEGIN TRAN first, check @@ROWCOUNT, then COMMIT
- ...

Even though MySQL requires statements to be terminated, the last one in a MySQL batch (or highlighted code) *doesn't* require it. So it's back to good old developer discipline and separation of environments

Comment: Minor nitpick: it's the (Microsoft) *tools* that require that, not the statement as such.